Including .yml file in PYPI package
I'm currently building a python package, which I need to upload to Pypi.
My problem:
I need a config.yml to be accessible by my package so users can tweak it for their own connections to foo/bar. I have included one in the root directory of my project. Post build (with twine) and upload to test Pypi, when I download the package the config.yml file is not accessible in my virtual environment :
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /Users/l/dev/projfolder/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pkge/config.yml'

What I've done
I'm using setuptools for my backend, which looks like this :
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(
    name='pkge_name',
    version='0.0.7',
    description="pkge_desc",
    author="lll",
    author_email="lll@example.com",
    license='MIT',
    package_data={'': ['config.yml']},
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['ez_setup', 'examples','tests', 'tests.*', 'release']),
    include_package_data=True,
    url='pkge_example.com',
    install_requires=[
        'click',
        'requests',
        'python-dotenv',
        'keyring',
        'questionary',
        'inquirer',
        'datetime',
        'PyYAML'
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'example=example.commands.cli:cli',
        ],
    },
)

For reference, this is my file structure:
proj/
- pckge/
    - __init__.py
    - file_1.py
    - file_2.py
-MANIFEST.in
-config.yml
-LICENSE
-README.md
-setup.py
-requirements.txt

In my desperation, I have also created a MANIFEST.in file which includes the config.yml file, to no avail. I'm pretty sure this shouldnt be needed with my setuptools anyway.
I'm sure this is a dumb error (I'm new to packaging), but any help would be great!
